# Adding New Lines / Breaks / Paragraphs into a Long NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have an `NSString` that is derived from an Atom XML Feed. The data that I get back is full of HTML syntax, various tags, links and so forth. I take that entire string and run it through the `stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText` method that is part of the `MWFeedParser` library.

This works perfectly and gives me a very long `NSString` - basically the full news story of the feed i'm parsing.

I want to take that long single NSString and break it up into paragraphs to make it more readable in my app rather than one long scrollable list of un-formatted text. Is there anyway I can apply paragraphs or new lines and break the string up like that?

Comment: Are there newline/break characters in the string?

Comment: @MJN No. The stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText method strips everything out. It did have <p> tags but not \n. If it had \n in I would use something like replaceStringWithOccurencesOfString or something similar. It's essentially just pure, plain text.

Comment: Before you run your original html-included string through the html stripper, break up your original long string into arrays. Then you can further strip the html out of each array. What do you want to break on? I'll provide sample code for an answer.

Comment: I guess it would make sense to break on <p></p> and get the paragraphs as they are intended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split up your long string into an array of strings using `componentsSeparatedByString:`. Then for each element (paragraph) in the array, run the string through `stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText` to strip out remaining html tags.

You might want to do some more work on the contents or paragraphs after stripping the html tags.

```
NSString *htmlString = @"<p>first paragraph</p><p>second paragraph</p><p>thrid paragraph</p>";
NSArray *paragraphs = [htmlString componentsSeparatedByString: @"<p>"]; // still includes </p>
for (NSString *singleParagraph in paragraphs) {
    // strip out remaining html tags
    singleParagraph = [singleParagraph stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText];
}

// strip out empty or irrelevant indexes and paragraphs you don't need
```